# java swing: Is it possible change color of a specific string variable?

Tags: java, string, swing, text, colors

From the Question above, I've made a simple windows app similar to MSN and Yahoo Messenger. When a user types a message and hits the "SEND" button, The code below appends the user's name and message to the the textArea:

```
textArea_ChatLog.append(chatName + "\n" + " " + msgChat + "\n");
```

Which would display in this format:

```
Username
Message the user typed.
```

Is there solution to changing the color of "chatName?" The only information I've found pertains to changing the color of entire components (which is what I don't want).

Comment: Strings don't have colors.  You're asking about UI.

Comment: @SLaks Thats why I put "java swing:" and asked if it is "possible."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use HTML tags and style with swing components. Take a look at this tutorial - [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Comment: I checked it out, but nothing pertaining to changing appearance to individual string variables like mine. My string names can't be hard coded, because it is linked to whatever name I use to sign in as.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you should be using is [JTextPane/JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), for changing colours of random String Literals, try your hands on this code, seems like this is what you wanted :-)

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.*;

import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class TextPaneTest extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTextPane tPane;
    private JTextField tfield;
    private String username = null;

    public TextPaneTest()
    {
        topPanel = new JPanel(); 
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5)); 

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);            

        EmptyBorder eb = new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        tPane = new JTextPane();                
        tPane.setBorder(eb);
        //tPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        tPane.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tPane);

        topPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        tfield = new JTextField(10);
        tfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (tfield.getDocument().getLength() > 0)
                {
                    appendToPane(tPane, username + " : ", Color.MAGENTA);
                    appendToPane(tPane, tfield.getText() + "\n", Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    tfield.selectAll();
                }
            }
        });     
        topPanel.add(tfield, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);        

        getContentPane().add(topPanel);     

        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);           

        while (username == null)
        {
            username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter USERNAME : ");
        }
        tfield.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c)
    {
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

        int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
        tp.setCaretPosition(len);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        tp.replaceSelection(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    new TextPaneTest();
                }
            });
    }
}
```